# Play video on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, video-streaming

I want to play video from a URL.  How do I do this?

Comment: In what ways have you tried to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the url of video. If you have the vid in local file system fetch the path of it. And than open it with blackberry's default browser. The browser will automatically open it in default media player

Comment: i don't want to open it in browser. i want to create own video player.